# Private app to use facebook marketing api

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I want to use the marketing api to pull ad data from facebook, and according to the docs I need to create an app in order to have the access token to do so. So far so good.

Here's my problem:

I need to take the app out of development mode in order to manage more than 5 ads accounts.  But when I try to do so, I get a warning saying "Are you sure you want to make your app public? It will become available to everyone." I don't want the app to be publicly discoverable or accessible!  Any way to make the app "live" keep the it private?  I'm not even sure how it would be discoverable since I didn't create any pages for it.

Comment: No. You need to make it public.To search your app, type app name in search bar(on profile page) and select Apps category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to manage more than 5 accounts then you will need an upgrade from the **Development Level** to **Basic Level** of the [Marketing API access level.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access/)

> I need to take the app out of development mode in order to manage more
>   than 5 ads accounts.

Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: Thanks for this.  I work for an ad agency, automating data collection for campaign managers.  I just need to collect the ad data and write to our internal db. I really don't need or want any sort of user-facing app. I'm looking into requesting Basic Level access, but it requires an App Url, Privacy Policy, and Platform details none of which are relevant for my purposes.

Comment: In order to qualify for Basic Level you will need to fulfill the criteria listed in the doc that I provided; there is no way around it.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Bangdel.  I provided what I had and it was approved.  Very quick.  

I realize now that my initial confusion was over the app status being in development mode vs the api access being in development mode.